# Class(implementing the interface) and interface in same file and accessing the class from a main class in different package

Tags: java

I was going through some design pattern videos on YouTube, however I have a small doubt on some basic Java concept. I tried searching for solution, but was unable to find one. Below is my query.

I have some classes **Animal.java**, **Dog.java**, an interface **Fly.java** which also has a class named CantFly in same file. A main method CheckAnimal.java. Below is the code

**Animal.java**

```
package com.classification.pojo;

public class Animal {

    public Fly flyingType;

    public String tryToFly() {
        return flyingType.fly();
    }

    public void setFlyingAbility(Fly newFlyType) {
        flyingType = newFlyType;
    }

}
```

**Dog.java**

```
package com.classification.pojo;

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        super();
        flyingType = new CantFly();
    }

    public void digHole() {
        System.out.println("I am digging hole!");
    }
}
```

**Fly.java**

```
package com.designpattern.strategy;

public interface Fly {
    String fly();
}

class CantFly implements Fly {

    public String fly() {
        return "Can't fly";
    }
}

class ItFlys implements Fly {
    public String fly() {
        return "I can fly";
    }
}
```

**CheckAnimal.java**

```
package com.designpattern.main;

import com.classification.pojo.Animal;
import com.classification.pojo.Dog;
import com.classification.pojo.Fly;

public class CheckAnimals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal doggy = new Dog();
        System.out.println(doggy.tryToFly());
        doggy.setFlyingAbility(new ItFlys());
        System.out.println(doggy.tryToFly());
    }

}
```

In **CheckAnimal.java**, for doggy object to invoke **setFlyingAbility()** method correctly, Animal.java, Dog.java and Fly.java needs to be in same package. If I keep Fly.java in different package, I cannot access **CantFly()** constructor. I hope I have made my point clear.

-
Ishan

Answer (score 1):

That's right. You can make the `CantFly` class *public* to access it outside of it's package, but note that doing that requires you to put it in its own file.

That is: Create `CantFly.java` with the following content:

```
package whatever.package.you.want;
import com.designpattern.strategy.Fly;

class CantFly implements Fly {
    public String fly() {
        return "Can't fly";
    }
}
```

Also, it shouldn't be `new Fly.CantFly()` (since you haven't defined `CantFly` *inside* the `Fly` interface). It should be just `new CantFly()`.

---

If you really want to keep `Fly` and `CantFly` in the same file, you can let `CantFly` be an inner class:

```
interface Fly {
    ...

    class CantFly {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then instantiate it with `new Fly.CantFly()`. If you're fine with this, I'd probably recommend you to consider using an enum instead:

```
enum FlyCapability {
    CANT_FLY {
        @Override
        public String fly() {
            return "Can't fly";
        }
    },

    CAN_FLY {
        @Override
        public String fly() {
            return "Can fly";
        }
    };

    public abstract String fly();
}
```

Comment: You beat @jonskeet by 14 seconds!

Comment: Yes, I know it will work if I put CantFly class in a different file. However I want CantFly class to be in same file as the interface Fly it is implementing. I have changed some stuff for better understanding of Code. If I copy all the code in same package it works as expected. However suppose I move Fly.java in package as I have mentioned above it doesn't...

Comment: Updated my answer slightly.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `CantFly` without any access modifier:

```
class CantFly
```

... which means it's only accessible within the same package. Just make it public, and then you'll be able to use it within other packages. See the [Java tutorial on access modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more information. The same is true for the `ItFlys` class.

Additionally, you haven't imported the right package in your `CheckAnimal.java` file. You should be importing `com.designpattern.strategy.ItFlys`. You don't need to import `Fly` at all in `CheckAnimal.java`, as you're never referring to that interface directly in that file.

Comment: Apologies for some typo mistakes, I know CantFly is not a method. I have made changes and also updated with necessary comments. Thank You!

Comment: @icr: Why have you changed the question so much? You didn't need to introduce `ItFlys` at all - you've made most of the existing answers into nonsense. Fixing a typo is one thing, but some of the other changes are inconsequential *other* than to invalidate answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default modifier of a class is package-private, meaning it is visible only by classes in the same package.

You can simply make `CantFly` a public class defined in its own Java file.

`CantFly` is not nested inside the `Fly` interface, so you would need to call its constructor using `new CantFly()` instead of `new Fly.CantFly()`.

Comment: Oops I am sorry, I made a very big typo mistake, it should be doggy.setFlyingAbility(new CantFly());

Answer (score 0):

First Of all `Fly` is an interface that cannot be instantiate which you are doing in `CheckAnimal` class. 
Try this:-

```
package com.designpattern.main;
import com.classification.pojo.Animal;
import com.classification.pojo.Dog;
import com.classification.pojo.Fly;

public class CheckAnimals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Animal doggy = new Dog();
         doggy.setFlyingAbility(new CantFly());

    }
}
```

and `CantFly` is no a method it is a class.